# SQL Server 2019 Installation Exit code (-2068119551) error

Tags: sql-server, installation, ssms, sql-server-2019

[image]

I am trying to install MS SQL Server 2019 Evaluation version but I am getting the exit code (decimal) -2068119551 error. I disabled the firewall ad tried to install using admin account but was unable to resolve the issue. Any help is appreciated folks.

Comment: Check %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log for the detailed log files. You can update your question with details from the Summary log file in that directory (from the most recent , and the detailed logs in the subdirectories for every install attempt on the machine

Comment: Thanks to User Account Control, using an account in the Administrators group (or even the Admistrator account itself) is different than using the `Run as Administrator` option when right-clicking on the setup executable. How did you launch the setup executable?

Answer (score 1):

cdrive:/programfiles--> right click and go to properties--> go to advanced--> uncheck compress content--> and apply--> come out from advance and click apply, dialog box will appear and then continue.

Comment: this does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

Try running the setup file as administrator by right clicking and selecting run as administrator.

This solved the exact same error code for me with SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition on an Azure vm running windows server 2019

Comment: Thank you this solved it for me (SQL Server 2019 on Windows Server 2019). Note that running setup via right click .. Run as Administrator is also necessary if you are already logged in as Administrator.